# Windows Phone Application error

Tags: windows-phone

I want to create an application with list Picker  i have this message

"The type 'toolkit: ListPicker is found. Make sure there are no missing assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been generated."

Answer (score 0):

`ListPicker` is a part of the [Windows Phone Toolkit](https://phone.codeplex.com/). You can download it here or through [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit).